# Django-allauth override signup method in customform

Tags: django, django-allauth

I am having trouble with django-allauth. I create my customform and it works fine, but now I need to override the signup

I tried this:

```
class CustomSignupForm(SignupForm):

password1 = SetPasswordField(label="Password")
password2 = PasswordField(label="Conferma Password")
first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='Nome')
last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='Cognome')
data_di_nascita = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='Data di nascita',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'gg/mm/aaaa'}))
citta = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='Città', required=False)
regione = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='Regione', required=False)
stato = CountryField(blank_label='Nazione',blank=True).formfield()
termini_e_condizioni = forms.BooleanField(label='termini_e_condizioni',widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class':'your_class'}))
privacy = forms.BooleanField(label='privacy',widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class':'your_class'}), required=False)
newsletter = forms.BooleanField(label='newsletter',widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class':'your_class'}), required=False)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(CustomSignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['password1'].label = "Password"
    self.fields['password2'].label = "Conferma Password"
    self.fields['password1'].widget = PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Password'})
    self.fields['password2'].widget = PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Conferma Password'})
    for field in self.fields:
        help_text = self.fields[field].help_text
        self.fields[field].help_text = None
        if help_text != '':
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({'class':'has-popover', 'data-content':help_text, 'data-placement':'right', 'data-container':'body'})


def confirm_password(self):
    print('entered confirm_password')
    if ("password1" in self.cleaned_data
            and "password2" in self.cleaned_data):
        print('password fields found')
        if self.cleaned_data['password1'] != self.cleaned_data['password2']:
            print('le password non corrispondono')
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("You must type the same password"
                                          " each time."))
        print('passwords equal')
        return self.cleaned_data["password1"]
    else:
        print('passwords not found in form')
        raise forms.ValidationError(_("Password not found in form"))


def signup(self, request, user):
    print("-------------------------------------------------------------------OK----------------------------------------------")
    user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
    user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
    user.save()
    userpost=User.objects.get(username=self.cleaned_data['username'])
    userpost.personal_data.birthdate = self.cleaned_data['data_di_nascita']
    userpost.personal_data.country = self.cleaned_data['stato']
    userpost.personal_data.subcountry = self.cleaned_data['regione']
    userpost.personal_data.city = self.cleaned_data['citta']
    userpost.personal_data.created = timezone.now()
    userpost.personal_data.save()
    userpost.markeringpreference.subscribed=self.cleaned_data['newsletter']
    userpost.newsletterpreference.subscribed=self.cleaned_data['newsletter']
    userpost.markeringpreference.save()
    userpost.newsletterpreference.save()
    return user
```

Is it correct? I ask because it doesn't save `personal_data` and never prints the first line (`prin('———ok——-')`)

My version of Django is 2.2 and django-allauth 0.41.0

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. If you're subclassing `allauth.account.forms.SignupForm`, then `confirm_password` isn't a method that will be called. Maybe you meant `clean_password2`? Also if `signup()` isn't called then it probably means your form wasn't valid so your view never called the `save()` method (which calls the `signup()` method).

Comment: But the user save fine only the personal_data markeringpreference and newsletterpreference don't save. Because i havent signup view how can i test if form is valid?

Comment: what is `SignupForm`? Where do you import it from?

Comment: from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm,SetPasswordField, PasswordField

Comment: And how did you tell your app to use this custom signup form?

Comment: In setting.py ACCOUNT_FORMS = {
    'signup': 'Ciclods.plugin_extension.plugin_extension.allauth.custom_forms.CustomSignupForm',
    }